# Prove $x^a y^b z^c$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}^3$ where $a,b,c$ are whole numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity, epsilon-delta

I need to prove the following formula:

$x^a y^b z^c$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}^3$ where $a,b,c$ are whole numbers.

**My try:**

We need to find a relation between $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.

We are given:

$\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 + (z-z_0)^2} < \delta$

We need to show:

$|    x^a y^b z^c   -   (x_0)^a (y_0)^b (z_0)^c  |  \leq A [(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 + (z-z_0)^2] < (A\ \delta ^2 = \epsilon) $

What shall be $A$?

I tried to figure out what $A$ will be for a long time and then gave it up. Can anybody here help?

Comment: Finite product of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: Thanks!!! That does it.

Comment: By the way, just out of curiosity, what shall be $A$? Is it impossible to find or possible (but very hard)?